# Install NumPy for Windows 10 and Python 3.4.2 64 bit

Tags: python, numpy

I'm going crazy installing NumPy on Windows 10 and Python 3.4.2 64 bit.
I downloaded the file numpy-1.10.4+mkl-cp34-cp34m-win_amd64.whl from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy. When I give the command to install

```
pip install numpy-1.10.4+mkl-cp34-cp34m-win_amd64.whl
```

But I obtain 
    numpy-1.10.4%2Bmkl-cp34-cp34m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

I tried also with 32bit version, same.

Someone can use NumPy on Windows?
How can I do?

Thank you

Comment: I'm so sorry, I've looked everywhere and I have not seen this pag. Thank you! :-)

Comment: @robertogaravaglia is it a duplicate? Does the other Q provide you with enough information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use Numpy with Windows, I'm using Canopy Editor which have a very good library. You can upload Numpy from that lib and install it.
After that, Numpy works very well !

You can also download Visual Studio Code which have also a library with Numpy